# Can not get data from form ui component to controller in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I create form ui component, and controller save, but i can't get data to controller, i tryed this code but it not show error, not get data.

```
$data = $this->getRequest()->getParam();
```

It show This page isn’t working, but if i echo 1; exit; it show 1.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
$data = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
```

(or)

```
$data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
```